# Was the scene of Remy savouring food in Ratatouille animated by a person with synesthesia?

Tags: animation, ratatouille

In [this post](https://www.reddit.com/r/CasualConversation/comments/gevafn/i_just_found_out_remy_the_lil_rat_guy_from_the/) the poster says:

> Then this particular scene of Remy savouring food came along (with like swirls of different colours popping up in the background) and I thought, "Huh. That reminds me of synaesthesia."
>
> I googled it and apparently the animator who worked on that particular scene does have synaesthesia!!!

This is that particular scene:

I follow the animator website and find out [his production behinds that scene](https://www.gagneint.com/Final%20site/Animation/Pixar/Ratatouille.htm). However there is still no information to confirm that he actually has [synesthesia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synesthesia), or it's just his imagination about the phenomenon.

So is there a way to confirm that he actually has that?

Comment: Why the downvote?  Yes this person asked and answered, but that is allowed here.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

He has another animation named [Synesthesia](https://www.gagneint.com/Final%20site/Animation/Synesthesia/Synesthesia.html). This indicates that he has a decent interest in the topic.

In his another animation, [Sensology](https://www.gagneint.com/Final%20site/Animation/Sensology/Sensology.html), he says:

> As Paul played, I closed my eyes and had an intense synesthetic experience.

He also had an interview with Psychology Today, describing his synesthesia in details: [Michel Gagne Animates Synesthesia for Major Films](https://www.psychologytoday.com/us/blog/sensorium/201309/michel-gagne-animates-synesthesia-major-films-0)

So we can confirm that Michel Gagné does have synesthesia.

Comment: I'm sure you're right and the author does indeed have Synesthesia (they made a film with that title, so at the very least they have an interest in the subject) but "Renowned for his unique vision" isn't evidence of that. That just means this person is famous for having a distinctive personal style. One can be renowned for their unique vision and not have synesthesia in any way. You could even say it of a blind person, it doesn't refer to actual sight, and it's a relatively common idiom. Also, I believe you meant  "biography" not "bibliography" but I don't have the rep to edit.

Comment: yes, thanks for the correction. I wonder why no one has pointed it out. As for the bit "Renowned for his unique vision", I know that it's just an indirect evidence. The real evidence is in the bit he says in Sensology. I put it there because it can still supporting the conclusion I guess

Comment: Yes, absolutely, the second part is quite conclusive. It's just that the first isn't even indirect evidence, there are [thousands of occurrences](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22unique+vision%22) of the phrase "unique vision" in published books and I don't think any native speaker would associate this rather common phrase with synesthesia.

Comment: I agree with terdon here. I think it's very, very unlikely that the phrase "renowned for his unique vision" refers to synesthesia. I think this answer would be better if that part were removed.

Comment: @TannerSwett and tardon: I see. Thank you for pointing that out

Comment: FWIW, would "unique vision" be understood as an euphemism about having different eye condition?

Comment: https://www.psychologytoday.com/us/blog/sensorium/201309/michel-gagne-animates-synesthesia-major-films-0

Comment: @MeatTrademark thanks for the link. I wonder why I didn't find it earlier